# Selecting an optimal parameter value for desired mean

Tags: r

My first time posting here.

I have data that looks like the following example:

> C1   C2   C3   C4
>   1 1.33 1.86 1.91 2.51
>   2 1.54 1.74 1.98 2.25
>   3 1.75 1.97 2.20 2.59

I want to find a parameter value (x) such that the mean number of values less than x per row is closest to 1. For example, for the above data, I know that x = 1.75 gives me desired value of x. However, I would like to use R to find it when I have 1,000's of rows and 100's of columns.

> x = 1.75
>   dataset.counts <- rowSums(dataset[,] < x)
>   dataset.counts 
>   [1] 1 2 0
>   mean(dataset.counts)
>   [1] 1

Can I use optim() to find x?

Comment: You could do that, but since you're finding a zero (that the mean you compute minus the parameter you seek is zero or close to it), the more obvious function to try would be `uniroot`.

Comment: @Glen_b, Thanks, it worked. I used the following code:<BR><BR>    R1   R2   R3   R4
1 1.33 1.86 1.91 2.51
2 1.54 1.74 1.98 2.25
3 1.75 1.97 2.20 2.59
> 
> f <- function(x){
+ 1 - mean(rowSums(dataset[,] < x))
+ }
> 
> uniroot(f, c(0,6), tol= 1e-10)
$root
[1] 1.747159

$f.root
[1] 0

$iter
[1] 8

$estim.prec
[1] 0.008522727

Comment: Code won't look right in a comment. Perhaps you could write it up as an answer. I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Glen_b, thanks. I am posting console for the code that worked great for me using uniroot. Thank you very much for your help.

> dataset
>       R1   R2   R3   R4
>   1 1.33 1.86 1.91 2.51
>   2 1.54 1.74 1.98 2.25
>   3 1.75 1.97 2.20 2.59
>
> f <- function(x){
>   + 1 - mean(rowSums(dataset[,] < x))
>   + }
>
> uniroot(f, c(0,6), tol= 1e-10)
>   $root
>   [1] 1.747159

$f.root
[1] 0

$iter
[1] 8

$estim.prec
[1] 0.008522727

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about R. But I can tell you a general algorithm that will run in O(n logn) where n is the number of data points (should run in under a second for a data set with 10 million numbers).

1. store all the elements in an array `a`
2. sort `a`
3. make variables `x` and `x_idx`
4. run a binary search on `i` in the range [0, n-1] inclusive.
5. at each step in the search:

   - run through every row and count the number elements in that row that are less than or equal to `a[i]`
   - set `mean` to the total divided by the number of rows.
   - if `mean` is closer to 1 than `x`, set `x_idx` to `i` and set `x` to `a[x_idx]`
   - if `mean` is less than 1, restrict your search to the top half.
   - else if `mean` is greater than 1, restrict your search to the bottom half.
   - else if `mean` is 1 break;
6. return x;

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I appreciate your response. uniroot seems to work in R. If I run into any trouble with that, I will give your solution a try. Much appreciated.